# How to group and count the number of occurence of item in comma delimited string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Student class with the following properties

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Assume we have a list of students like below

```
var students = new List<Student>();
students.Add(new Student { Name = "John", Subject = "Math"});
students.Add(new Student { Name = "Bob", Subject = "English, Math"});
students.Add(new Student { Name = "Jane", Subject = "Math, History, Art"});
students.Add(new Student { Name = "Jim", Subject = "English"});
```

I want to group the students by subject and count the subject.

So the output would be

```
Math, 3
English, 1
History 1
Art 1
```

How can I achieve the outcome using linq?

Answer (score 8):

```
students.SelectMany(arg => arg.Subject.Split(new []{','})) // split the Subject-property on commas
        .Select(arg => arg.Trim()) // get rid of the whitespaces after commas
        .GroupBy(arg => arg) // you can inject an equality comparer here, to achieve case insenstive grouping
        .Select(arg => new
                       {
                         Subject = arg.Key,
                         Count = arg.Count()
                       }); // TODO output these objects to your console..
```

Answer (score 6):

Basically, what you want to do is first get the subjects of all students, and just collect those. To do this, you need to split the `Subject` by the comma, and then trim the results (to get rid of whitespace around the comma). This gives you a list of all subjects.

Now all you need to do is count how often each subject occurs in the list. To do this, you can use just `GroupBy`. Afterwards, you have all subjects grouped by the name, so you only need to count how many there are in each group.

You can then collect that result for example in a dictionary like this:

```
IDictionary<string, int> subjectCount = students
    .SelectMany(s => s.Subject.Split(','))
    .Select(s => s.Trim())
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count());

foreach (var count in subjectCount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", count.Key, count.Value);
}
```

---

Btw. it seems a bit weird that `Student.Subject` is a comma-separated string of the student’s subjects. You should consider using a list there, so that you have separated values from the beginning. And since the property contains multiple subjects, you should pluralize the name too:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @user3851289 Please mark the answer as accepted. A "thank you" comment is kind, but nevertheless not seen as essential content.